# Installation OpenLiteSpeed Web Server on Amazon Linux (RHEL)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, yum, dependencies, litespeed

I'm just trying to install OLS on my Amazon Linux 2 instance, but i received errors at first and all last steps. Here is the explaination about:

1. When i added recommended by guide repository, i receive error:

   ```
    failure: repodata/repomd.xml from litespeed: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
   ```

   http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/centos/8/x86_64/repodata/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found

To fix it, i just replace $releaseserver to 8 (as i can see at http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/centos/) at link http://rpms.litespeedtech.com/centos/$releasever/$basearch/
and... it works!
But after that, when i trying to install, i receive these dependency errors:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, priorities, update-motd
191 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package lsphp73.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-common(x86-64) = 7.3.18-1.el8 for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1(OPENSSL_1_1_0)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libssl.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libcrypto.so.1.1()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libargon2.so.1()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package openlitespeed.x86_64 0:1.6.14-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-xml for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-process for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-pdo for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-opcache for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-mysqlnd for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-mcrypt for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-mbstring for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-imap for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: lsphp73-gd for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnsl for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package lsphp73.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libargon2.so.1()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-common.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-common-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-gd.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.7()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libXpm.so.4()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libX11.so.6()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-imap.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc-client.so.2007()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-imap-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-mbstring.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
---> Package lsphp73-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
---> Package lsphp73-opcache.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-opcache-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-pdo.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
---> Package lsphp73-pecl-mcrypt.x86_64 0:1.0.3-1.el8.7.3 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmcrypt.so.4()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.3-1.el8.7.3.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-process.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
---> Package lsphp73-xml.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.24)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-xml-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.22)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-xml-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.18)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-xml-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.13)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-xml-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1(LIBXML2_1.0.11)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-xml-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxslt.so.1()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-xml-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libexslt.so.0()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-xml-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package openlitespeed.x86_64 0:1.6.14-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libnsl for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package openssl11-libs.x86_64 1:1.1.1c-3.amzn2.0.1 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libX11.x86_64 0:1.6.7-2.amzn2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libX11-common >= 1.6.7-2.amzn2 for package: libX11-1.6.7-2.amzn2.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb.so.1()(64bit) for package: libX11-1.6.7-2.amzn2.x86_64
---> Package libXpm.x86_64 0:3.5.12-1.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package libc-client.x86_64 0:2007f-16.el7 will be installed
---> Package libmcrypt.x86_64 0:2.5.8-13.el7 will be installed
---> Package libxslt.x86_64 0:1.1.28-5.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package lsphp73.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libargon2.so.1()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-common.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-common-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-gd.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.7()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-opcache.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-opcache-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package openlitespeed.x86_64 0:1.6.14-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libnsl for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libX11-common.noarch 0:1.6.7-2.amzn2 will be installed
---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.12-1.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libxcb-1.12-1.amzn2.0.2.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libargon2.so.1()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-common.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-common-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-gd.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.7()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-opcache.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-opcache-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package openlitespeed.x86_64 0:1.6.14-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libnsl for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.8-2.1.amzn2.0.2 will be installed
---> Package lsphp73.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libargon2.so.1()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-common.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-common-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-gd.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libwebp.so.7()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpng16.so.16()(64bit) for package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package lsphp73-opcache.x86_64 0:7.3.18-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit) for package: lsphp73-opcache-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64
---> Package openlitespeed.x86_64 0:1.6.14-1.el8 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libnsl for package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: lsphp73-opcache-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64 (litespeed)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64 (litespeed)
           Requires: libargon2.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64 (litespeed)
           Requires: libwebp.so.7()(64bit)
Error: Package: openlitespeed-1.6.14-1.el8.x86_64 (litespeed)
           Requires: libnsl
Error: Package: lsphp73-common-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64 (litespeed)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64 (litespeed)
           Requires: libpng16.so.16(PNG16_0)(64bit)
Error: Package: lsphp73-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64 (litespeed)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)
Error: Package: lsphp73-gd-7.3.18-1.el8.x86_64 (litespeed)
           Requires: libpng16.so.16()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have no idea how to fix it.
Thanks to your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to install packages for RHEL/CentOS on Amazon Linux 2. These packages are not compatible, as Amazon Linux 2 is not compatible with RHEL/CentOS and will not run software packaged for RHEL/CentOS except by sheer accident.

To resolve the problem, use CentOS 8 or RHEL 8, the correct distributions for the package you are trying to install. Do not use Amazon Linux.

Comment: Thanks! I'm confused, because at openlitespeed.com the guide has Amazon Linux installation mention ( https://openlitespeed.org/kb/install-ols-from-litespeed-repositories/#CentOS_5_6_7_8_Debian_7_8_9_10_Ubuntu_1204_1404_1604_1804_Amazon_Linux )

Comment: @anskibenko You should report the error to the maintainer of that web page. That software is not packaged for Amazon Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it! Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Need 50 reputation... so instead of a comment, here's my "answer".
Michael is right, but the answer could be a little confusing.  This is just a clarification.
The OLS install from OLS repositories guide is not for "Amazon Linux" or "Amazon Linux 2".  Your OS version is the problem.  You CAN run that install process on AWS/EC2... just use a different Linux OS to start with - like Ubuntu or CentOS.
Amazon Linux (2) is a different Linux distro, even if based off of CentOS, it isn't CentOS.